# How to set up conditional dependency for Stack project?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to enable my Stack-based Haskell project to apply a certain GHC plugin when the user requires it.

I have successfully added the `-fplugin` flags through the `ghc-options`. As far as I know I have to add the plugin package as a dependency in my `package.yaml` file. However I would like to configure the project so that the extra dependency is only added if the user requires it (with a flag set, environment variable or some other means).

I have tried to use the `when` keyword in the `package.yaml` to conditionally enable the dependency:

```
when:
  - condition: flag(useplugin)
    then:
      dependencies: [ myplugin ]
    else:
      dependencies: []
```

However this results in an error coming from cabal:

```
- 0:0: These flags are used without having been defined: myplugin
```

I couldn't find the option for `package.yaml` which would generate the flag definition (like described [here](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-package.html#pkg-section-flag-flag)) in the generated cabal file.

Comment: See the description for `flags` at https://github.com/sol/hpack#top-level-fields.